# What is the difference between events and propositions?

Tags: logic, reference-request

The title says it all.

I would be interested as well in references (papers or books).

Comment: Could you provide some more context to this question? What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve and what have you done to find the answer yourself?

Comment: See http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/ and http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/events/

Comment: way too broad, like asking the difference between cars and food

Answer (score 1):

A proposition is an abstract, linguistic entity expressing something about the world and having a truth value, whereas an event is a concrete, occurrent entity in space-time.

Without context the question is puzzling: not much relate or opposes the two concepts specifically (no more than fact, statement, object, process...). I had not imagined there could be confusion between the two.
Therefore I am in pain of providing references, apart from general introductions to metaphysics, philosophy of language, and the like.

Comment: There is also a theory of the 'event' in French structuralism - Derrida mentions it in his post-structuralism; and Badiou names his book after it - *Being and Event*; and, no, I have no real idea what this event is, except it has no real connection to the notion of event in spacetime.

Comment: Recently, some philosophers, most notably Scott Soames, have held that propositions are event types (not tokens): http://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/678/docs/BookChapters/New_Thinking_About_Propositions/NTP_Chapter_6.pdf

Comment: @sequitur thank you for this reference-although it should be noted that Soames talks about a particular category of event (cognitive events).